# Vue.js: How can I prevent `vue-cli-service --modern` from building the legacy bundle?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, deployment, build, vue-cli

[Modern mode of Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#modern-mode) always builds the two bundles: modern and legacy.

```
$ vue-cli-service build --modern

-  Building legacy bundle for production...
(snip)
DONE  Compiled successfully in 42448ms 
(snip)
-  Building modern bundle for production...
(snip)
DONE  Compiled successfully in 39693ms
(snip)
DONE  Build complete. The dist directory is ready to be deployed.
(snip)
Done in 89.76s.
```

So it takes twice as long than I build the app without `--modern` option. It's a waste of time when the app is targeted to only modern browsers.

Is there a way to prevent the Vue CLI from creating the legacy bundle?

Comment: williangd also mentioned the same issue on github: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1465#issuecomment-501365256.

Comment: And the question was answered in the issue you linked, so what else are you wondering?

Comment: @JacobRaihle Right. Recently I figured the solution out from LinusBorg's answer in the issue as you pointed. The task left to me is posting the answer to this question, after confirming the result of solution on my project.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**You don't need to use `--modern` flag**. 
Instead, just adjust `.browserslistrc` like as follows:

```
last 2 years
```

Vue CLI's ["Modern" mode](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#modern-mode) stands for the mode which builds two bundles -- legacy and modern --, but it does not represent the appropriate way to make your Vue app code "modern".
If you want only the modern output, just adjust what browsers are targeted.

See also [this comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1465#issuecomment-501388265) on the vue-cli issue.

Comment: Banged my head for almost 2 hours with all the comments and suggestions in github issues and nothing worked. This is the only thing that worked for me finally! Thank you.

Comment: Is the contrary also true i.e. if you use --modern mode, then the browserslist isn't needed?